# Webview activity crashes

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview

I am using a navigation drawer in which while clicking on textview to open new activity(web view), but my activity is crashing

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
View myView;
 private WebView mywebview;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_layout,container,false);



    mywebview =(WebView) container.findViewById(R.id.web);
    WebSettings webSettings=mywebview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mywebview.loadUrl("http://www.proxbotcreatn.com/");
    mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    return myView;
}
```

}

Comment: show your logcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass **myView** instead of **container**.

**Wrong**

```
 mywebview =(WebView) container.findViewById(R.id.web);
```

**Proper Way**

```
 mywebview =(WebView) myView.findViewById(R.id.web);
```